# Excel simulation creating column according to value in the row

Tags: excel, simulation

I want to generate random value according to the value in the row.
I tried: `=if( row:row>50;Rand ())`
But this gives me the `Rand()` value only on one column. 
At the end I generate the amount of values I want but not in the way I want.

Example:

```
3 rd rd rd
2 rd rd
1 rd
```

I have 4 000 simulations

Comment: Oops i didn't see the editing thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a macro.

Say your values start in cell A1, select cell B1 and run the macro below, you will get your random numbers in separate cells:

```
Sub CreateRandomNumbers()
Dim i As Integer: Dim q As Integer
Dim startingRow As Integer: Dim startingColumn As Integer
Do While ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value <> ""
    'Store number of random numbers required in "q"
    q = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
    'Store starting row and column
        startingRow = ActiveCell.Row
        startingColumn = ActiveCell.Column
    'Exit sub if q = 0
    If q = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No random number required."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'Calculate random numbers
    For i = 1 To q: ActiveCell.Value = Rnd(): ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select: Next i
    'Go back to starting cell
    Cells(startingRow, startingColumn).Select
    'Go to next row in the same columns
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
End Sub
```

Looks like this:

[image]

I hope it helps.